# MailEnable outgoing mails not working

Tags: email, dns

I have VPS server where I have installed and setup the Mail enable.
Mail received to my domain correctly but sending email is not working.

Below is the error message in Debug files, I am trying to send the email to gmail account.

I have configured DNS address as 8.8.8.8 in screen from [LINK](https://www.mailenable.com/documentation/8.0/Standard/webframe.html#SMTP_props_-_General.html)

Please advise what I am missing.

```
   08/26/14 04:03:32    ME-E0038: [506629A77F504145BCB93AF20809FEE3.MAI] Communications Error: Socket connection to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com failed (error 10060). The host was either not contactable or it rejected your connection. Socket Family = 2; Host=74.125.207.27; Port=25
08/26/14 04:03:32   ME-I1350: [506629A77F504145BCB93AF20809FEE3.MAI] Attempting to connect to MX 3 of 5 (alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com).
08/26/14 04:03:32   ME-E0038: [5A869FB21DD040BF806315BC5F2C7E1D.MAI] Communications Error: Socket connection to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com failed (error 10060). The host was either not contactable or it rejected your connection. Socket Family = 2; Host=74.125.207.27; Port=25
08/26/14 04:03:32   ME-I1350: [5A869FB21DD040BF806315BC5F2C7E1D.MAI] Attempting to connect to MX 3 of 5 (alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com).
08/26/14 04:03:32   ME-E0038: [8C7F27633A4C4B1AADAEE61DC2590955.MAI] Communications Error: Socket connection to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com failed (error 10060). The host was either not contactable or it rejected your connection. Socket Family = 2; Host=74.125.207.27; Port=25
08/26/14 04:03:32   ME-I1350: [8C7F27633A4C4B1AADAEE61DC2590955.MAI] Attempting to connect to MX 3 of 5 (alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com).
08/26/14 04:03:32   ME-IXXXX: [506629A77F504145BCB93AF20809FEE3.MAI] DNS resolved to the following record: IP Address=74.125.21.26, Family=2, Type=1, Protocol=6
08/26/14 04:03:32   ME-IXXXX: [8C7F27633A4C4B1AADAEE61DC2590955.MAI] DNS resolved to the following record: IP Address=74.125.21.26, Family=2, Type=1, Protocol=6
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this? If yes, please direct me to solution as I am having the same problem on godaddy vps.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a  vps such as godaddy, make sure you use their relay servers because the Godaddy kind of servers **do not allow outbound port 25 directly from servers to the internet** ..

You have to go to SMTP setting properties and select Smart Host and enable smart host and use vps service provider email relay server..

http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2014/09/mailenable-smtp-error-10060-godaddy.html